# Referencing the killed object

Tags: ewam

I am getting the following error. Can somebody help?

> aICCNTRequiredRenewalQuestionnaire has a list of aICCNTRRQPolicyInfo
>   W:\wide\WideDll\WREFTO.CPP                aReftoType..GarbageMarkFrom 
>   MajorError                BATCHUSER                        ** no
>   object **                ** no object **
>   aICCNTRRQPolicyInfo Add =2E7D:63A0 NSId = 0 Id = 0 Version =
>   2147483647 referencing the killed object  with type
>   <_RefMyRequireRenewalQuestionnaire0aICCNTRRQPolicyInfo>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you cancel the main object and do not cancel the `listOf` object linked to it.

Check if the class `aICCNTRequiredRenewalQuestionnaire`  has be been cancelled anywhere in the code.

Example :

- Check for similar code shown below. Note `pRenewalQuestionnaire` is a variable type of class `aICCNTRequiredRenewalQuestionnaire`.

`pRenewalQuestionnaire.CancelObject(pRenewalQuestionnaire)`

- Need to verify whether `listOf` of class `aICCNTRRQPolicyInfo` has been cancelled too.

So the solution would be to first cancel all the `listOf` object and then cancel the main object.

```
forEach theRRQPolicyInfo in pRenewalQuestionnaire.MyRRQPolicyInfo

   theRRQPolicyInfo.CancelObject(theRRQPolicyInfo)

endFor

pRenewalQuestionnaire.CancelObject(pRenewalQuestionnaire)
```

Comment: Thanks. Ill give that a try.